# Validation of Models with Different Scale Data

Tags: r, validation, normalization

I created a model for two different datasets that have different scales. When checking which one performed better, I am struggling with figuring out the best methodology. My top choices right now are `R^2`, `RMSE`, and `variance`. However, R^2 seems to be the only option that works best in my opinion because it doesn't seem to take into account the scale of the data but wondering if there are options such as normalizing the numbers etc.

Below is a sample situation:

```
      Date      Group      Actual_Values       Predicted_Values
2020-04-24          A              0.181                  0.140
2020-04-27          A              0.190                  0.127
2020-04-28          A              0.188                  0.126
2020-04-29          A              0.188                  0.123
2020-04-30          A              0.185                  0.122
2020-05-01          A              0.178                  0.124
2020-05-04          A              0.182                  0.118
2020-05-05          A              0.180                  0.120
2020-05-06          A              0.178                  0.120
2020-05-07          A              0.180                  0.121
2020-05-08          A              0.184                  0.124

2020-04-24          B              86.24                  86.25
2020-04-27          B              94.00                  86.65
2020-04-28          B              98.44                  86.88
2020-04-29          B              107.3                  87.05
2020-04-30          B              94.26                  87.27
2020-05-01          B              96.71                  87.42
2020-05-04          B              92.28                  87.59
2020-05-05          B              90.97                  87.73
2020-05-06          B              87.47                  87.80
2020-05-07          B              88.93                  87.90
2020-05-08          B              92.41                  87.93
```

From this dataset I tested the following code:

```
library(ModelMetrics)
with_rmse<- historical_results %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(
    RMSE = rmse(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values)
    ,R2 = cor(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values)^2
    ,variance = abs(var(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values))
  )

Group           RMSE            R2      variance
    A     0.05929241    0.02067078  3.548883e-06   
    B       8.461625    0.02991999     0.5624356
```

So for example, the above results like `8.4` for `RMSE` may actually be good but looks bad just because the original values were higher than `A`. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: RMSE is dependent on the scale, it weights more on larger values. R square is ok if the there are no outlier values in your group. For example if group A is to have one that is around 10.. it will throw your R squared off

Comment: you can also try mean relative absolute error, like mean ( (actual - predicted)/actual )